# Создание SQL запроса с несколькими выборками

Tags: sql

Имеется таблица `users`, `orders`

```
Таблица `users`
|id|  
|1 |  
|2 |  

Таблица `orders`  
|id|pay|user_id| 
---------------- 
|1 | 1 |  1    |  
|2 | 0 |  2    |  
|3 | 0 |  1    |
```

pay - указывает оплатили(1), не оплатили(0)
Необходимо вывести таблицу `users` с такой структурой

```
|id|count(with_pay)|count(total_orders)|  
---------------------------------------- 
|1 |      1        |        2          |  
|2 |      1        |        0          |
```

Словом, чтобы в 1 запросе выводились пользователи с количество всех ордеров(total_orders) и количеством купленных (with_pay)

Как правильнее организовать запрос?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вот например так:

```
SELECT users.id, sum(orders.pay), count(orders.id)
FROM orders INNER JOIN users ON users.id = orders.user_id
GROUP BY users.id
```

Здесь считаем сумму оплаченных заказов, и количество всех заказов, и группируем по пользователям. Что бы понять, как это работает, посмотрите `sql агрегатные функции`.